# Calculate discipline level from attendance record given a set of rules

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have written an attendance calculator that compares a set of rules against an  employee's attendance record and determines what level of progressive discipline that employee is at (how much trouble they are in).

**Information:**

1. The rules are provided as a JSON object whose information comes from inputs on the page
2. The employee's attendance record is provided as a nested  array of "incidents". Incidents can be 0, .5, or 1 points each depending on the type (tardy , absent, left early, etc...)
3. So far in testing, the below functions as expected

Mainly, how could I have written `checkForPD()` better/shorter/smarter?
(but I'll take critique on any of the rest of the code too)

```js
// define our attendance rules from the inputs 
var rules;
function getRules(){    
        rules =  {"coaching":{ "incidents": $('.incidents:eq(0)').val(), "days": $('.days:eq(0)').val() },
                "verbal":{ "incidents": $('.incidents:eq(1)').val(), "days": $('.days:eq(1)').val() },
                "written":{ "incidents": $('.incidents:eq(2)').val(), "days": $('.days:eq(2)').val() },
                "suspension":{ "incidents": $('.incidents:eq(3)').val(), "days": $('.days:eq(3)').val() },
                "termination":{ "incidents": $('.incidents:eq(4)').val(), "days": $('.days:eq(4)').val() }
               };
}
getRules();
// define the team member's attendance record
var incidents = [
    [moment('1/8/2015','l'), 'Absent', '1234567','1'],
    [moment('1/12/2015','l'), 'Absent', '1234567','1'],
    [moment('1/20/2015','l'), 'Absent', '1234567','1'],
    [moment('2/11/2015','l'), 'Absent', '1234567','1'],
    [moment('3/9/2015','l'), 'Absent', '1234567','1'],
    [moment('3/18/2015','l'), 'Early Out', '1234567','0'],
    [moment('3/19/2015','l'), 'Absent', '1234567','0'],
    [moment('3/20/2015','l'), 'Absent', '1234567','1'],
    [moment('4/10/2015','l'), 'Absent', '1234567','1']
];
// function to sort a given nested array by date at the index provided by col
function sortByDateInCol(arr, col) {
        return arr.sort((function (index) {
            return function (a, b) {
                return (a[index] === b[index] ? 0 : (a[index] < b[index] ? -1 : 1));
            };
        })(col));
}
incidents = sortByDateInCol(incidents,0);

// got is an object to keep up with what level of progressive discipline the team member is on and when that level was administered
var got ={"coaching":false, "verbal":false, "written":false, "suspension":false, "termination":false};
var ttlPoints=0, ptsFrmLast=0, first=false;

function checkForPD(scale,attendance){
    ttlPoints=0;
    // loop through each incident in the team member's attendance record
    $.each(attendance, function(i,incident){
        var occurred = incident[0]; 
        var points = incident[3];
        ttlPoints = ttlPoints + Number(points);
        // if no first date, this is the first occrence set this incident's date as the first
        if(!first){
            resetPD(occurred);
            ptsFrmLast = ptsFrmLast + Number(points);
            // if TM has enough points for next level, administer PD
            if(ptsFrmLast>=scale.coaching.incidents){
                got.coaching=occurred; 
                $('.occurred').eq(i).addClass('coaching');  
            }
        }
        // does not yet have any progressive discipline, check for coaching
        else if(!got.coaching){
            // find the date x number of days since the first incident where x is the number of days from our rule
            var periodEnd = first.clone().add(scale.coaching.days,'days');
            if(occurred <= periodEnd){
                 // if this new incident occurred before the peroid ended, progress towards the next level of PD
                 ptsFrmLast = ptsFrmLast + Number(points);
                // if TM has enough points for next level, administer PD
                if(ptsFrmLast>=scale.coaching.incidents){
                   got.coaching=occurred; 
                   $('.occurred').eq(i).addClass('coaching');  
                }
            }
            // if no other incidents in the period, reset the first date to this one 
            else{
                resetPD(occurred);
            }  
        }
        else if(!got.verbal){
            var periodEnd = first.clone().add(scale.verbal.days,'days');
            if(occurred <= periodEnd){
                 ptsFrmLast = ptsFrmLast + Number(points);
                if(ptsFrmLast>=scale.verbal.incidents){
                   got.verbal=occurred; 
                   ptsFrmLast=0;
                   $('.occurred').eq(i).addClass('verbal');  
                }
            }
            else{
                resetPD(occurred);
            }             
        }
        else if(!got.written){
            var periodEnd = got.verbal.clone().add(scale.written.days,'days');
            if(occurred <= periodEnd){
                 ptsFrmLast = ptsFrmLast + Number(points);
                if(ptsFrmLast>=scale.written.incidents){
                   got.written=occurred; 
                   $('.occurred').eq(i).addClass('written'); 
                   ptsFrmLast=0; 
                }
            }
            else{
                resetPD(occurred);
            }             
        }
        else if(!got.suspension){
            var periodEnd = got.written.clone().add(scale.suspension.days,'days');
            if(occurred <= periodEnd){
                 ptsFrmLast = ptsFrmLast + Number(points);
                if(ptsFrmLast>=scale.suspension.incidents){
                   got.suspension=occurred; 
                   $('.occurred').eq(i).addClass('suspension'); 
                   ptsFrmLast=0; 
                }
            }
            else{
                resetPD(occurred);
            } 
        }
        else if(!got.termination){
            var periodEnd = got.suspension.clone().add(scale.termination.days,'days');
            if(occurred <= periodEnd){
                 ptsFrmLast = ptsFrmLast + Number(points);
                if(ptsFrmLast>=scale.termination.incidents){
                   got.termination=occurred; 
                   $('.occurred').eq(i).addClass('termination');
                   ptsFrmLast=0;  
                }
            }
            else{
                resetPD(occurred);
            } 
        }
        ttlPoints = ttlPoints + Number(points);
    });    
}
function resetPD(when){
                getRules();
                got ={"coaching":false, "verbal":false, "written":false, "suspension":false, "termination":false};
                ptsFrmLast=0, 
                first = when;  
}
// populate the progressive discipline table from the team member's attendance record
var rows = '<tr><th>Date</th><th>Type</th><th>Points</th><th>Remove</th></tr>';
$.each(incidents, function (i, e) {
    rows = rows + '<tr><td class="occurred">' + e[0].format('L') + '</td><td>' + e[1] + '</td><td>'+ e[3] +'</td><td><a href="#" data-obj-id="' + e[2] + '" class="btnLink">Delete</a></td></tr>';
});
$('#incidentsTable').html(rows);

checkForPD(rules,incidents);

// update the 
$('.incidents, .days').change(function(){
    $('.occurred').removeClass("coaching verbal written suspension termination");
    resetPD(false);
    checkForPD(rules,incidents);
});
```

```css
.btnLink {
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: #0355A4;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: -top:20px;
}
#incidentsTable td {
    padding:10px;
}

.coaching{
    background-color:#fde4cf;
}
.verbal{
    background-color:#ffffbe;
}
.written{
    background-color:#ff636b;
}
.suspension{
    background-color:#a18bbc;
}
.termination{
    background-color:#4acbff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>coaching</td>
        <td>
            <select class="incidents">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2" selected>2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>incidents in</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="coaching" class="days" value="30" />
        </td>
        <td>days</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>verbal</td>
        <td>
            <select class="incidents">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3" selected>3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>incidents in</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="verbal" class="days" value="60" />
        </td>
        <td>days</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>written</td>
        <td>
            <select class="incidents">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2" selected>2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>incidents within</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="written" class="days" value="90" />
        </td>
        <td>days of the verbal</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>suspension</td>
        <td>
            <select class="incidents">
                <option value="1" selected>1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>incidents within</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="suspension" class="days" value="180" />
        </td>
        <td>days of the written</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>termination</td>
        <td>
            <select class="incidents">
                <option value="1" selected>1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>incidents within</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="termination" class="days" value="180" />
        </td>
        <td>days of the suspension</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br>
<br>
<table id="incidentsTable"></table>
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, your indentation and styling can be improved, e.g:

- Whitespace between operators
- Your usage of `}else`s
- various lines have incorrect indentation

I would suggest putting your code into a tidier like [JSFiddle's Tidy](http://jsfiddle.net).

You have a lot of duplicate logic, like:

> ```
>              ptsFrmLast = ptsFrmLast + Number(points);
>             if(ptsFrmLast>=scale.written.incidents){
>                got.written=occurred; 
>                $('.occurred').eq(i).addClass('written'); 
>                ptsFrmLast=0; 
>             }
>         }
>         else{
>             resetPD(occurred);
>         }             
>     }
> ```

I would suggest using a function for that, and passing in the specific variables that change: like `scale.written` for example.

Answer (score 0):

#### Styling

Besides the things Quill mentioned, you are mixing functions and regular code. This is messy.

You are not declaring variables at the top. Javascript will move variable declarations to the top automatically. This is called "variable hoisting". Not declaring the variables at the top yourself can cause issues when a variable is defined when you expect it not to be.

You are meddling in the global namespace. Consider putting your code in an IIFE.

#### Functions meddling with global variables

One of your functions is changing a variable "got" which is declared outside that function. This makes the existence of that function questionable. Either make "got" an argument, or change the function so that it is self-contained again.